# how to remove ballon tips from a software using reshacker?

Tags: usb

I need to run apo usb autorun complitly silent.But when i plug a usb stick in, a balloon tips appear in the tray containing usb properties. I do not need this balloon tips.Can anybody please tell me how can i remove this balloon tip using reshacker or something else?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible without cracking the tool. The ballon tooltip is shown because of a Win32 API call:

http://www.stromcode.com/2008/03/02/cwin32-the-system-tray-and-balloon-tips/

The only way is to set the registry key to completely disable all ballon tooltips.

Comment: Please tell me how to completely disable all ballon tooltips.

Comment: The following KB article tells you how: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307729